# hibernate mapping java Long to MySQL BIGINT error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have a Mysql table name customer where

column Acc_no and Cust_ID are of type BigInt(14) and BigInt(10) respectively

and I want to check for values in MySQL through Spring MVC Hibernate

Bean Class customer

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Cust_ID")
long Cust_ID;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Acc_No")
long Acc_No;

@Column(name="C_New_Pwd")
String C_New_Pwd;
```

While in CustomerDAOImpl I did this

```
    long custid=Long.parseLong(clog);
    long acc_no=Long.parseLong(accno);

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    String SQL_QUERY =" from com.mla.Customer as o where o.Cust_ID=? and o.Acc_No=? and o.C_New_Pwd=?";
    Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);

    query.setParameter(0,(Long)custid);
    query.setParameter(1, (Long)acc_no);
    query.setParameter(2, pwd);
    List list = query.list();
```

**Exception :** *com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException: '9.87654321E9' in column '10' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER.*

Long casting in setParameter I did it on purpose but no help same exception.

Comment: Why don't you use BigInteger instead of long?

Comment: @KillerDeath Ok So I did use this but why do I have to import if its a variable I hope there will be no problem in checking value with normal int with this BigInteger

Comment: @KillerDeath And how will I parse string to BigInteger then..... see my code

Comment: Which string? I am under impression that yout cust_id and acc_no are too large to fit into standard integer

Comment: The error message you get shows that you're trying to store a too large value in a column of type *INTEGER*, not *BIGINT* (or to read a BIGINT value in a Java property of type int or Integer) . Fix your database column definition or mapping. Also, respect the Java naming conventions, and don't name SQL_QUERY a variable that holds a HQL query.

Comment: @KillerDeath I also know this that range doesn't fit into integer but I took long and mapped it with bean class column of mysql bigint of same column

then I tried BigInteger c=new BigInteger(acc_no); //acc_no is type String

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution:

```
// Convert Long to String.
String custID = Cust_ID.toString();

// Then create the BigInteger
BigInteger bigIntegerCustID = new BigInteger( custID );

query.setParameter(0, bigIntegerCustID);
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks  still getting the error ......  '9.87654321E9' in column '10' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER but column 10 is my C_New_Pwd I am not getting why it is showing for column 10 please reply

Comment: did you try to execute your query directly from mysql workbench ?